# What are some of the special / hidden features in Mathematica? And is there a list of all of them anywhere?

Tags: front-end, special-functions

There are a few features in Mathematica that I've come across over the years which implement their own interfaces, tools, and or GUIs (MoleculeDraw[] and Canvas[] being two great examples) and each time I come across one they tend to be extremely useful as they add functionality you typical wouldn't expect. So my question is, are there other functions / menu's and tools like this, and if so what are they and how do they work?

[image: Molecule Draw GUI]

For clarity, I'm specifically asking about features that add functionality to Mathematica outside of the typical "function takes inputs and gives outputs" sense. Taking MoleculeDraw[] as an example, we can see this symbol adds a full blown molecule editor to Mathematica which is much more than a simple function as shown above. And likewise, canvas adds functionality similar to something like MS Paint.

Additionally, I'm not asking about anything like Resource Functions or 3rd party palettes, and am strictly interested in things built into mathematica. A good example of a hidden palette would be one like the Notation Palette for instance which comes up when you load the built-in Notation Package using Get["Notation`"] as shown below:

[image: Notation palette]

Finally, I would also say that functions outside of the global scope, and which don't have a documentation page like FEPrivate`AddSpecialArgCompletion for instance would also count as hidden features assuming they have some utility to users.

I hope this question isn't to vague, and that this can become a useful resource for people hoping to discover some of the lesser known features the ship with Mathematica.

Comment: The [documentation for the Notation package](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/Notation/tutorial/NotationSymbolizeAndInfixNotation.html) documents the Notation palette, so it's not really "hidden" imo. Also [big-list] type questions, when not closed since they are by def. "too broad", are usually Community-Wiki (no rep points).